# json to javascript variable zendesk

Tags: javascript, html, json, zendesk

I'm trying to retrieve the amount of open tickets from the zendesk api for a specific user. However I can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '500' of undefined
```

The json format:

```
{
"user": {
    "id": 500,
    "url": "https://zendesk/api/v2/users/500.json",
    "name": "Random name",
    "email": "not important",
    "created_at": "2016-05-18T15:26:43Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-04T06:23:35Z",
    "time_zone": "Brussels",
    "phone": null,
    "shared_phone_number": null,
    "photo": {
        "url": "https://google.com",
        "id": 504,
        "file_name": "keep-calm-and-shut-up-im-your-system-administrator.png",
        "content_url": "https://google.com",
        "mapped_content_url": "https://google.com",
        "content_type": "image/png",
        "size": 3298,
        "width": 80,
        "height": 50,
        "inline": false,
        "thumbnails": [
            {
                "url": "https://google.com",
                "id": 90752965,
                "file_name": "not important",
                "content_url": "https://google.com",
                "mapped_content_url": "https://google.com",
                "content_type": "image/png",
                "size": 3298,
                "width": 32,
                "height": 20,
                "inline": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "locale_id": 1005,
    "locale": "nl",
    "organization_id": 501,
    "role": "admin",
    "verified": true,
    "external_id": null,
    "tags": [],
    "alias": "",
    "active": true,
    "shared": false,
    "shared_agent": false,
    "last_login_at": "2018-07-04T06:23:35Z",
    "two_factor_auth_enabled": null,
    "signature": "",
    "details": "",
    "notes": "",
    "role_type": null,
    "custom_role_id": null,
    "moderator": true,
    "ticket_restriction": null,
    "only_private_comments": false,
    "restricted_agent": false,
    "suspended": false,
    "chat_only": false,
    "default_group_id": 503,
    "user_fields": {
        "agent_ooo": false
    }
},
"open_ticket_count": {
    "500": 15
}}
```

This is my javascript code:

```
        <script>
    function getJSON(url) {
    var resp ;
    var xmlHttp ;

    resp  = '' ;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xmlHttp != null)
    {
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

    return resp ;
}
   var gjson ;
    gjson = getJSON('https://zendesk.com//api/v2/users/me.json? 
    include=open_ticket_count');

console.log(gjson.open_ticket_count["500"]);

</script>
```

Can someone help me out? I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong (the zendesk urls are the correct urls in the actual script and they can access it)

TLDR: I need to retrieve the variable from: open_ticket_count from a json.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getJSON` function will not wait for the request to actually go through. A function like this would return the responseText only once it's finished:

```
const getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      let status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status, xhr.response);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

You can then use this to get the Zendesk JSON:

```
getJSON('https://zendesk.com//api/v2/users/me.json?include=open_ticket_count', (status, gjson) => {
    console.log(gjson.open_ticket_count["500"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exacty without rest of the environment but I assume this will work:

```
    var gjson ;
    gjson = getJSON('https://zendesk.com//api/v2/users/me.json?include=open_ticket_count'');
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(gjson); // assuming getJSON returns the json as string, this is async, make sure next row has the data needed on time or rewqork this as promise
    console.log(jsonObj.open_ticket_count["500"]);
```

So basically call the entire JSON and then parse it from string to object before using it like object

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '500' of undefined

Which says that `gjson.open_ticket_count` is undefined.

You haven't actually parsed the JSON and trying to get a property of a string not the parsed JSON.

Try parsing it first.

```
var gjson;
gjson = getJSON('https://zendesk.com//api/v2/users/me.json?include=open_ticket_count');
var gobj = JSON.parse(gjson);
console.log(gobj.open_ticket_count["500"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON in order to access it. Use below code

```
<script>
    function getJSON(url) {
       var resp ;
       var xmlHttp ;

       resp  = '' ;
       xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

       if(xmlHttp != null)
       {
           xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
           xmlHttp.send( null );
           resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
       }

       return resp ;
    }

    var gjson ;
    gjson = getJSON('https://zendesk.com//api/v2/users/me.json? 
    include=open_ticket_count');

    gjson = JSON.parse(gjson)

    console.log(gjson.open_ticket_count["500"]);

</script>
```